# Angular Service called twice in lazy loaded modules

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an Angular application where I have implemented lazy loading. It is working fine but when ever I am making any HTTP request to the server the action is happening twice.

In my current structure I have created a shared module to store all the common modules and components. I am using ajax service to make all the api calls to backend, AuthTokenService is to store and handle Authentication token-

**Feature Module -**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

//Importing HTTP Intercepter and services
import { HTTPInterceptorProvider } from '@/core/_HTTP-interceptor';
import { AjaxService, AuthTokenService } from '@/core/_services';

//Importing pipes
import { SummaryPipe } from '@/core/_pipes';

//Externel Plugins Modules
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

import { AnimatedNumbersComponent } from '@/modules/shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AnimatedNumbersComponent,
    //Pipes used are listed here
    SummaryPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    AnimatedNumbersComponent,

    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        AjaxService,
        AuthTokenService,
        HTTPInterceptorProvider
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**App Module -**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { FeatureModule } from './modules/featured/feature.module'

import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
import { AppComponent } from '@/app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule, // NGX Spinner
    FeatureModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App Routing Module -**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard, SecureOuterPagesGuard, SecureInnerPagesGuard } from "@/core/_guards";

// Home page of the application
import { IndexComponent } from '@/modules/index/index.component';
import { 
  LoginComponent, 
  RegisterComponent,
  ForgetPasswordComponent,
  ResetPasswordComponent 
} from '@/modules/auth';

import {
  PageNotFoundComponent,
  InternalServerErrorComponent
} from '@/modules/shared';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'forget-password',
    component: ForgetPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password',
    component: ResetPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: 'internal-server-error', 
    component: InternalServerErrorComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [
  IndexComponent,
  LoginComponent, 
  RegisterComponent,
  ForgetPasswordComponent,
  ResetPasswordComponent,
  SessionTimeOutComponent,
  PageNotFoundComponent
]
```

**Ajax Service -**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, timeout } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()

export class AjaxService {

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  apiCall(
    data: any,
    url: any,
    method: 'DELETE' | 'GET' | 'HEAD' | 'POST' | 'JSONP' | 'PUT',
    isRawUrlFormat: boolean = false
  ){
    // Checking if the provide url is in raw format or not
    if (isRawUrlFormat == false) {
      url = environment.API_URL + "/" + url;
    }

    // creating request variable of type Observable so that any component can subscribe it
    let request: Observable<any>;

     // setting methods of request type and passing params (url, data, headeers and observe to access complete response)
     switch (method) {
      case 'GET':
        request = this._http.get(url, { observe: 'response' });
        break;
      case 'POST':
        request = this._http.post(url, data, { observe: 'response' });
        break;
      case 'PUT':
        request = this._http.put(url, data, { observe: 'response' });
        break;
      default:
        request = this._http.request(method, url, { observe: 'response' });
    }


    // returning api result with status, if found any error returns that error
    return request.pipe(
      timeout(environment.AJAX_TIMEOUT),
      map((apiResult : HttpResponse<any>) => {
        const status : number = apiResult.status;
        let responseObject = apiResult.body;
        responseObject.status = status;
        // if found status 202 means has a refreshtoken in response then again setting it in localstorage
        if (status == 202) {
          localStorage.setItem("userToken", apiResult.body.response.data.token);
        }
        return responseObject;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: add your ajax code

Comment: I have added the ajax service

Comment: you should be using `{providedIn: 'root'}` for core services like this, but generally that wouldn't explain why things are being called twice.  it just means there are multiple copies floating around, not that it's being injected in duplicate.  Are you sure it's not the call and an options call bfore it? also it could be your interceptor causing problems.

Comment: I was using {providedIn: 'root'} but the result was same so I moved it feature module.

Comment: it seems ```{providedIn: 'root'}```  did not solve the problem, try to add take(1) after pip

Comment: Also added that one. Still happening the  same issue.

Comment: @RahulKundu did you resolve the issue?